# Does OpenCV 2 provide any api for fast fragment decoding of encoded image?

Tags: c++, opencv

So I have `200k x 200k` `jpeg` and `png` encoded images. I need to get a segment (say a Rectangle `{( 1k, 1k); (2k, 1k)}` ) of such encoded image not loading given image info ram entirely.  Is such thing possible via OpenCV or there is some other crossplatfom library for such operations?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV doesn't have an API where you provide a Rect to `imread()`. I am not aware of any other library that has this feature.

Looking at the source in `modules/highgui/src/grfmt_jpeg.cpp`, it seems  possible to add this feature by  subclassing JpegDecoder and providing a `bool  readData( Mat& img, Point location )` as well as custom version of `imread()` to call it.